# Error C2280 while creating a std::thread without initialization in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I want to create a thread object in my class/struct but don't want to initialie immediately during declaration. Intead want to do it later. Hence, I did as in below code snippet, I'm getting this compilation error. How do I fix this ?

> error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting
>   to reference a deleted function

I observed the line causing this error is :

> ```
>   std::thread t2;
> ```

Does it mean that we can't just declare a std::thread without initializing ? This contradicts the answer in this thread [Is it possible to define an std::thread and initialize it later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375998/is-it-possible-to-define-an-stdthread-and-initialize-it-later)

```
struct Abc
{
    int a;
    std::thread t2;
    void mem1()
    {
        printf("mem1\n");
    }

    void mem2()
    {
        printf("mem2\n");
        std::thread t1(&Abc::mem1, Abc());
        t2.swap(t1);
        printf("after spawning t1\n");
        t2.join();
    }
};
```

**Error Details:**

> > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(611): error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function 1>
> >     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> >     12.0\VC\include\thread(70) : see declaration of 'std::thread::thread' 1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated
> >     function 'Abc::Abc(const Abc &)

Comment: This code is ok. It works here: https://ideone.com/xRjkcv. I thik the problem is somewhere else. Please post the rest of your program or try cleaning/rebuilding the whole thing...

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error is telling you that you are trying to copy a struct `Abc` which has a member `std::thread`. This is not possible because `std::thread` cannot be copied.

If you would have posted the entire error message including the code that it first points to (i.e. the line of code actually invoking `Abc`'s copy constructor), I could provide you with a more complete solution.

---

**The old answer is kept below but I believe it is incorrect in defining the cause of your specific issue. The ramble about compiler-generated move constructors is still valid in its own right.**

Your code is fine. The compiler is failing to compile the call to `swap`, which in the case of move-only types relies on the move constructor of the types involved. Your `std::thread` won't have it explicitly defined, so a conformant compiler will generate it in this case.

Visual Studio 2013 does not automatically generate move constructors. This seems like a bug they could have worked around (by explicitly defining it for their `std::thread` implementation, and probably every other `std` class (template)). Make sure you update your compiler to VS 2013.5 (update 5) and see if that helps.

If that does not work, get a newer version of Visual Studio. The problem of not generating move constructors is fixed in VS 2015. Also VS 2017 is out. The latter is a lot better and a lot stricter when it comes to standard c++, even though it still fails to compile lots of "basic" SFINAE.

Comment: with vs2013.5 upgrade also I'm seeing the same issue. I've constraints not to upgrade to VS2015 or VS2017. Also my code nees to be OS agnostic. If C++ standard allows declaration of threads without initialization then why doesn't all compilers adhere to c++ standard. Why do they have their customizations ? Wil this work on linux, mac , android ?

Comment: Why don't all compilers adhere to the standard? Well, most do quite well, it's usually VS that forgets about some of the details (or big parts). VS 2013's C++11 support is just not very good.

Comment: Because a mysterious bug is all that is needed to rejuvenate your enthusiasm for programming and standard reading. VS will always be here for you. Apparently not in 2017 though

Answer (score -6):

Call a different constructor. That line calls the default constructor, which is defaulting to the move constructor, which is deleted or something lol. The answer in this question is pretty illuminating:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264984/c-compiler-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-in-visual)

Comment: please keep it professional/helpful - "lol" isn't helpful. The default constructor doesn't default to the move constructor. Link-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Then why is it throwing that error when he calls the default constructor? Are you sure?

Comment: It calls the copy constructor. That's not the default constructor. And, no, the copy constructor also doesn't default to the move-constructor, which also isn't deleted. See the other answer, really.