# std::thread in-class initializer failure

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11, stdthread

I understand from my previous [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963121/error-c2280-while-creating-a-stdthread-without-initialization-in-c/44963294?noredirect=1#comment76903700_44963294) that it migth not be possible to create a std::thread without initialization.

BUt WRT below code snippet, I see I'm not even able to create a std::thread even with initialization as a data member of a class/struct in C++.

It complains with compilation error "Function threadfunction is not a type name", irrespective if the function is within class/struct or outside (global). Please refer below example. 
Seems like there is some rivalry between class/struct and std::threads. Seeing so much of issues.

```
int f1234()
{
std::cout<""f1234";
}
struct Abc
{
    int a;
    void mem1()
    {
        printf("mem1\n");
    }
    std::thread mt(f1234); // Function f1234 is not a type name
    std::thread mt1(mem1); // Function mem1 is not a type name

}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with threads. Try a string or a vector or an int and see.

Comment: Also, you misunderstood. You can default initialize a thread.

Comment: To do inline-initialization you either have to use assignment-syntax or curly-braces. **But** that's not the only problem you have: The function `Abc::mem1` is a *member* function. Those need to be called on an *object* which you don't have when doing inline-initialization.

Comment: By the way, you should probably read about [constructor member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Does this correct this issue. I have chnaged the way std::thread is initialized ?

std::thread mt = std::thread(f1234); // Function f1234 is not a type name

std::thread mt1 = std::thread(&Abc::mem1); // Function mem1 is not a type name